# Reduce length of vertical line between two minipages

Tags: spacing, minipage, line

Consider the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

The actual outcome is shown on the left. The desired outcome with a shorter vertical line between the two minipages is shown on the right.  I tried to use `\vrule height 1ex` etc. to shorten the vertical line, to no avail. Is there a way to shorten the vertical line?  Ideally, though not at all necessarily, it would include a  fraction of the full vertical length to draw the line (e.g., 0.1 for 1/10th of the vertical distance, 0.5 for half way, and so on).

[image]

Comment: I also tried `\vline`, which gives the same result.  I'm not clear on the differences between `\vline` and `\vrule` in this context...

Comment: please have a look at the answer below if it suits the requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule depth 0.6ex\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```